# Seleccionar los valores de una lista usando otra lista

Tags: html, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Buenas noches a todos.

Tengo dos listas, una de habilidades y otra lista con las habilidades que posee el User logueado. Necesito mostrar todos los items de la lista  habilidades y que esten seleccionados los que esten en la segunda lista.

Este es mi codigo que por los momentos solo muestra los que estan en la lista de habilidades por usuario. Se muestran como una columna con un checkbox y al lado un select.

```
@if (ViewBag.Habilidades!= null)
    {
        foreach (var item in ViewBag.Habilidades)
        {
            if (ViewBag.HabilidadesUser!= null)
            {
                foreach (var item2 in ViewBag.HabilidadesUser)
                {                       
                    if (item2.Habilidad.Id == item.Id)
                    {

                        <div class="card-block">
                            <h6>@item.Description</h6>
                            <div class="col-lg-1">
                                <input class="to-labelauty-icon labelauty" checked="checked" type="checkbox" id="@item.Description" style="display: none;">
                                <label for="@item.Description"><span class="labelauty-unchecked-image"></span><span class="labelauty-checked-image"></span></label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <select required="" class="form-control" id="selectYears" type="text">
                                    <option selected value="0">None</option>
                                    @foreach (var item4 in ViewBag.Years)
                                    {
                                        <option value="@item4.Id">@item4.Description</option>
                                    }
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr />
                    }                       
                }
            }
            else
            {
                <div class="card-block">
                    <h6>@item.Description</h6>
                    <div class="col-lg-1">
                        <input class="to-labelauty-icon labelauty" type="checkbox" id="@item.Description" style="display: none;">
                        <label for="@item.Description"><span class="labelauty-unchecked-image"></span><span class="labelauty-checked-image"></span></label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <select required="" class="form-control" id="selectYears" type="text">
                            <option selected value="0">None</option>
                            @foreach (var item4 in ViewBag.Years)
                            {
                                <option value="@item4.Id">@item4.Description</option>
                            }
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr />
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se me ocurrio esto y funciono:

```
 @if (ViewBag.Habilidades!= null)
    {
        foreach (var item in ViewBag.Habilidades)
        {
            if (ViewBag.HabilidadesUser!= null)
            {       
                List<Model.HabilidadesUser> listInte = ViewBag.HabilidadesUser;
                 
                if (listInte.Any(x => x.Habilidad.Id == item.Id))
                {
                    foreach (var item2 in ViewBag.HabilidadesUser)
                    {
                        if (item2.Habilidad.Id == item.Id)
                        {

                            <div class="card-block">
                                <h6>@item.Description</h6>
                                <div class="col-lg-1">
                                    <input class="to-labelauty-icon labelauty" checked="checked" type="checkbox" id="@item.Description" style="display: none;">
                                    <label for="@item.Description"><span class="labelauty-unchecked-image"></span><span class="labelauty-checked-image"></span></label>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <select required="" class="form-control" id="selectYears" type="text">
                                        <option selected value="0">None</option>
                                        @foreach (var item4 in ViewBag.Years)
                                        {
                                            <option value="@item4.Id">@item4.Description</option>
                                        }
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <hr />
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <h6>@item.Description</h6>
                        <div class="col-lg-1">
                            <input class="to-labelauty-icon labelauty" type="checkbox" id="@item.Description" style="display: none;">
                            <label for="@item.Description"><span class="labelauty-unchecked-image"></span><span class="labelauty-checked-image"></span></label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <select required="" class="form-control" id="selectYears" type="text">
                                <option selected value="0">None</option>
                                @foreach (var item4 in ViewBag.Years)
                                {
                                    <option value="@item4.Id">@item4.Description</option>
                                }
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                }
            }
            else
            {
                <div class="card-block">
                    <h6>@item.Description</h6>
                    <div class="col-lg-1">
                        <input class="to-labelauty-icon labelauty" type="checkbox" id="@item.Description" style="display: none;">
                        <label for="@item.Description"><span class="labelauty-unchecked-image"></span><span class="labelauty-checked-image"></span></label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <select required="" class="form-control" id="selectYears" type="text">
                            <option selected value="0">None</option>
                            @foreach (var item4 in ViewBag.Years)
                            {
                                <option value="@item4.Id">@item4.Description</option>
                            }
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr />
            }
        }
    }
```